# Qt C++ - How to get the current Row and Column of a QPlainTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Hello World, I am working on a text editor in Qt c++ and I would like to know how to get the current row and column of a QPlainTextEdit. The reason I need it is to put it on the status bar of my app and I have no ***IDEA*** on how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call the QPlainTextEdit's textCursor() method to get a QTextCursor object representing the current position of the text-editing caret.  You can then call blockNumber() to get the current row, and positionInBlock() to get the position within the row (i.e. the column).

You'll probably also want to connect the QPlainTextEdit's cursorPositionChanged() signal to a slot in your program, so that you can update your display as the text-cursor moves around.

Comment: yeah man I get it, the problem is that I don't know how to use the code so i don't know if you could show me a little example on how to use it, please it will be really appreciated and thanks for understanding my question.